# how to make one of two functions

Tags: javascript, function

I call the function with and without a parameter. I don't know how to unite them into one. Thanks for help.

Function1

```
    normalizeTime(time) {

      var date = new Date(time * 1000);
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
      return strTime;
    },
```

Function2

```
    getAmPmTime() {

      var date = new Date();
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12;
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
      return strTime;
    },
```

Comment: What have you tried thusfar?

Comment: Call `normalizeTime()` without an argument and check what `time` will be (`console.log(time)`)

Comment: And, how can you write ternary operations but not realise a simple if would solve your problems?

Comment: Thank you all I do not understand how I did not notice such a simple solution. I need a break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check whether there is a parameter or not within the function. Sample implementation:

```
normalizeTime(time) {
  var date = time ? new Date(time * 1000) : new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm just learning and many times I don't notice simple solutions

Comment: @MartinBlaščák you are welcome. If this is the solution that you are looking for, please approve my answer.

Comment: @MartinBlaščák you upvoted my answer, You have not approved the same. :)

Comment: I still have something to learn :) for example to use stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

What about conditionally check if 'time' is available? inside your function:

```
let date = null;
if (time) {
  date = new Date(time * 1000);
} else {
  date = new Date();
}
```

This way, if the function is called without any arguments, a new date object will be created. If not, it will set the date with the time argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm just learning and many times I don't notice simple solutions

Comment: And that's ok! We've all been there! Consider marking this as the answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using default parameter like this:

```
joinedFunction(time = null){
      var date = time ? new Date(time * 1000) : new Date();
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
      return strTime;
}
```

if you do not pass anything(or a falsy parameter), it will be the same as calling your `getAmPmTime` function and if you pass a time, it will be the same as calling your `normalizeTime` function.

Comment: Is't this overkill for a simple A/B situation? Also not usable for IE.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm just learning and many times I don't notice simple solutions